# Find the distance between the middle of square and right angle in right triangle.

Tags: geometry

> Lenghts of legs in right triangle are $a$ and $b$. Outside of the triangle on hypotenuse was drawn square. Find the distance between the middle of square and right angle

Problem is easy if it is allowed to use trigonometry (law of cosines), but I was wondering about solution using more methods. Sadly I did not come up with something interesting, so I'm looking for some clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found much simpler solution.
[image: solution]

As we see the distance is half of the diagonal of the square that side is $a+b$, so that distance is $(a+b) \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : use ptolemy theorem. Right triangle and centre of square determine a cyclic quadrilateral
$$(a+b) \sqrt(\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}=\sqrt(a^2+b^2)(distance)$$
$$(distance)=(\frac{a+b}{\sqrt2})$$

Comment: You learn about ptolemy theorem rather later than about law of cosines (at least where Iive), so it may be considered more "advanced"

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Draw a isosceles right triangle taking the side $b$ as the hypotenuse.